# Rails 4: No route matches [PATCH] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Route:

```
 display_panel GET    /display/panel(.:format)                            display#panel
```

Controller:

```
class DisplayController < ApplicationController
  def panel
     @approval = Approval.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for approval,url: root_path, method: :patch  do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :pass%>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I think I do patch in a get action, this causes the error, so I hope to use `mathod: :patch` to correct it, but it still show me the same error.

I tried many solutions from other similar questions, still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your form like this:

```
<%= form_for @approval, url: [update_path] , method: :patch  do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :pass%>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[update_path] should be something like `approval_path`, not `root_path`. Run `rake routes | grep approval` to verify if you have setup `patch` route for approval.

Comment: I tried this,  but the problem is that if I define a update_path in route.rb and define a update method in the approval controller, I could not find approval by using approval = Approval.find(params[:id]), because I am doing update thing in an index page.

Comment: now that's confusing, if you don't have correct form endpoint or form url you cannot submit the form, simple as that. Doing update in index page does not mean using index url as the endpoint. The default index route is map to HTTP GET anyway. What you should be doing instead is redirecting to index page after succesful update.

Comment: Hi, you are correct, I think the biggest problem is that I did not kind a way to pass id to update action. I tried several way and it works now, thanks for your help.